# Selecting non-standard tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook

Is there a way to use jQuery to select the `<fb:like href="stackoverflow.com"></fb:like>` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape the `:` in the selector, like this:

```
$("fb\\:like")
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4vmPq/). Though...I can't guarantee this will work in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do $('[href=stackoverflow.com]')

Comment: This would be a very expensive selector, since it would check *all* elements in the DOM or that attribute...also what if you don't know the `href`? Presumably that's what the OP is trying to find out.