# How do I get the innertext value of a non-text XML RSS node using jQuery and/or javascript?

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

Here's the RSS/XML node (it's from my  - [picasaweb album feed](https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/vidanuevanaz)):

```
<gphoto:name>NurseryRenovation</gphoto:name>
```

I'm trying to get the "NurseryRenovation" text from inside the node using jQuery. Here's my code:

```
var itemTitle = $item.find("gphoto:name").val();
```

That returns "undefined" as does using .textContent, .innertext, and .innerxml. Using .text() returns an empty string. Using .contents returns what appears to be the inner workings of the "find()" method. Using $item.attr("gphoto:name") also returns "undefined". How can I get the inner content of the "gphoto:name" node using jQuery? This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

To grab tags that use colons, you have to escape the colons:

```
$('gphoto\\:name')
```

[Selecting non-standard tag with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190534/selecting-non-standard-tag-with-jquery)

That was what primary problem with what you were doing. After that, you really should look at the documentation for the different jQuery methods you mentioned.

`.text()` would seem to me to give you what you are looking for; the other functions can provide you different things. [ffr `.val()` is aimed at `<form>` elements, not content nodes]

Comment: Thank you. Assuming that works, that still only answers half my question. Now that I have the right tag, how do I get the text that sits between the opening and closing tags? Is it .val, .content, .text, .textContent, something else entirely?

Comment: @aaron.bynum I'd put my money on `.text()`, but that's something you can figure out now that you can properly select the element.

Comment: But that's my original question! If I could figure that out, I wouldn't have asked my question in the first place.